# Ember livereload not working when scss file updated in pod structure

Tags: ember.js, sass, livereload, ember-cli-pods

I have the following structure:

```
app/
  pods/
    components/
      user-login/
        component.js
        style.scss
        template.hbs
```

Template files and component files livereload correctly, however, when I save changes to my style files in Atom the changes are not applied on the webpage- they are only applied when I kill and rerun:

```
ember server
```

and reload the webpage.  I have installed the following:

```
ember-cli-styles-reloader
```

and I have tried adding:

```
"liveReload": true,
"watcher": "polling"
```

to:

```
.ember-cli
```

and I also tried adding these options to:

```
ember-cli-build.js
```

inside the app variable.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better option I believe, and I recommend to do this way:

First install [ember-cli-sass-pods](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-sass-pods) addon that uses ember-cli-sass (will install automatically) and then generate your style scss files into your pods directories.

to install

```
ember install ember-cli-sass-pods
```

then add

```
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {

    // you must add Watched folder to your Ember-Cli-Build.js
    sassOptions: {
      includePaths: ['app']
    }

  });
```

For example:

```
app/components/user-login
app/components/user-login/component.js
app/components/user-login/template.hbs
app/components/user-login/style.scss
```

just simply run this command:

```
ember g style [path] -p //your path now is components/user-login
```

there are more options that [you can read their documents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-sass-pods)

You are ,after installing and setting up that, able to use ember-cli-styles-reloader which probably will work smoothly. make sure you have followed all the rules that they mentioned in their documents to set up ember-cli-styles-reloader.

Comment: Thanks for the response, installing ember-cli-sass-pods package and adding the sassOptions variable to the Ember-Cli-Build.js got it so that reloading the page would update the style.  I had to remove ember-cli-styles-reloader from the package.json file and do an npm prune to get it so that it reloaded automatically when I saved the file.  Thanks again.